# Python hangs on socket receive while Wireshark shows all recieved

Tags: python, sockets, udp, python-3.6, freeze

I'm having trouble writing a udp socket receiver program.

I don't control the source of the transmission (only when to start it) - using `udp_source.start_transmission()`.

I'm also using Wireshark to monitor the network traffic.

According to Wireshark - I get all the data across. e.g: the source sends 60000000 bytes in udp packets.

However, in Python, the program hangs at `tmp = sock.recvfrom(1500)` after about 3/4 of the data.
e.g: it **does not** reach the stopping condition for the while loop.

```
    sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, 
                  type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 512 * 1024)
    sock.connect((ip, port)) 

    udp_source.start_transmission()

    cntr = 0
    l = []
    total_size = 60000000
    rec_bytes_len = 0

    while rec_bytes_len < total_size:
        r, w, e = select.select([sock], [], [sock], 60)
        if r:
            tmp = sock.recvfrom(1500)
            rec_bytes_len += len(tmp)
        cntr += 1
        if cntr % 1000 == 0:
            print(cntr)
```

I've tried:

1. Icreasing the receiver buffer:
   `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1024 * 512 * 1024)` - same behaviour
2. Adding a **massive** timeout `sock.settimeout(60)` - same behaviour
3. Making the socket unblocking - got a *non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately* exception

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

***EDIT***

Managed to get it working.
Turns out I didn't increase the buffer enough. 
Once I made the buffer very large (1 GB) I got all the data through.
Not sure why this is happening, but there it is...

Comment: Have you tried closing the socket once you're done talking? That might solve the problem; it seems like a buffering problem to me.

Comment: do you mean on the source side? I don't have access to it. I can just trigger a "pulse" of data. Otherwise - I never receive all of the data, I don't want to close the connection until all the data has passed. As to the buffering - I've tried increasing the buffer to 512 MB... didn't work

Comment: I can't really help with this, sorry. No clue! But closing the socket can trigger a flush... You could try flushing the buffer repeatedly from another thread, which is hackish but could work. (I'm guessing data might be dropped, though; ymmv.)

Comment: You don't specify your OS, but on linux, the `SO_RCVBUF` setting is limited by `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` (set to 212992 on my system). So the value you're setting may be silently reduced (a setting too large does *not* result in a `setsockopt` error). Is there no provision for re-sending datagrams in this system? UDP is "unreliable" by design -- if you don't consume data fast enough, datagrams are silently dropped. The user protocol is expected to allow for and handle that.

Comment: In your code, the `select` is pointless since you have nothing else to do (and will cost some tiny bit of performance, though probably not significant enough to explain your issue). You should just call `recvfrom` in the loop.

Comment: Finally (again, assuming linux), you can take a look at `/proc/net/udp` and/or use `netstat -su` to possibly confirm UDP drops.

Comment: Thank you all!     I've tried this code both on Ubuntu 14.04 and Win7 - Same results. I've added the select (after some reading here) in an attempt to 'check' the socket so it won't hang - didn't work. As for dropped UDP frames - will they appear in Wireshark as transmitted? I'll check for dropped frames as you suggested.